# Accessing data from controls within a C# Table control?

Tags: c#, controls

As the title suggests, I'm having trouble accessing data in my Table control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table).
The layout is basically a dynamic web-based spreadsheet with TextBox controls in each TableCell. I was trying to do something like the code below, but I can't access the data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Form.Textbox")
            { 
                TextBox t = c as TextBox;
                if (t.Text.Trim() != "")
                {
                    // Do more things based on t.ID...
                }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Table control? what is this? Did you mean DataTable? This is not a contol, but its a The DataTable is a central object in the ADO.NET library (and a class its self).

Comment: @MitjaBonca System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like:

```
        foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (control.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {
                //do your code..
            }
        }
```